# What is the difference between a torus and a flat torus?

Tags: general-topology

I read that $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\times\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is a torus and $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is a flat torus.
I want to know is the above facts are true,if false then what is the actual topological structure of torus and flat torus.

Comment: See the answer by levap at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280683/the-difference-between-the-algebraic-torus-and-the-geometric-torus/1280756), explaining the flat torus and the other one.

Comment: The duplicates linked above explain the answer to the question in your title. But you should also know that what you read in your first question is incorrect: $\mathbb R  / \mathbb Z \times \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R^2 / \mathbb Z^2$ are both flat tori, as long as one uses their Riemannian metrics that are induced from the natural metrics on $\mathbb R$ and on $\mathbb R^2$. If those words don't make sense, you'll have to learn some Riemannian geometry.